# Compare two arrays

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, ios5

I have two arrays:

```
array1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
array2=[1,2]
```

I want to compare weather elements in "array2" is present in "array1" or not.
If yes then I need to run a function, otherwise exit.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about enumerating over array1?

Something along the lines of

```
NSArray *array1 = ...;
NSArray *array2 = ...;

[array1 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([array2 containsObject: obj]) {
        // Run the function you wanted to
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the advantage of enumerating things, no need to create new objects if the intent is to run some code on only a few of the contained items. If the idea was to filter, then I'd use the NSMutableSet approach.

Comment: When i saw the question i decided to answer using NSMutableSet, but after reading your post i tought this is the best

Answer (score 7):

I have get the common items like this:-

```
NSMutableSet *idSet=[NSMutableSet setWithArray:Array1];
[idSet intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:Array2]];
NSArray *Common_array=[idSet allObjects];
```

in common array you can get the same object that are present in both array and is 0 object in 
Common_array than in both array there is none on object that are same.

Answer (score 1):

An easy logic way to do this would be a for loop:

```
for(int a = 0; a < array1.count; a++) {
    for(int b = 0; b < array2.count; b++) {
        if([[array1 objectAtIndex:a] isEqualToString:[array2 objectAtIndex:b]]) {
            //do something here
        }
    }
}
```